# How to handle the @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access rule on catch(err) blocks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, try-catch, eslint, typescript-eslint

I've recently added `eslint` to my Typescript codebase.

By default, it enables the `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access`.

And all of sudden, I'm getting tons of lint errors on my catch blocks.

[image]

Is there a good workaround for this?

Typescript does not allow me to type it as `Error` directly from the catch statement like `catch(err: Error)`.

I don't want to disable the rule completely, neither I want to add `eslint-disable` on every `catch(err)` block.

Comment: The `err` truly can be anything, which is a problem. You can type it as `unknown` to be safe and then narrow it down. But for me, in this situation I usually just disable type-checking and log `error.message` if `error` is an object

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you. Would you write an answer with a complete example of your suggestion?

Comment: I don't consider it to be a remotely elegant solution, there might be something better

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah, I've thought of some ways to handle it. But they all involve reassigning `err` to change its type and that feels repetitive and unnecessary. Let's see if someone comes up with some better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

There are various uncertainties in the `try` block, and JavaScript can throw not just an Error object, but even a `string`, or even `null` or `undefined`. We can use [instanceof-narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) to avoid such a warning

```
try {
  ...
} catch(e) {
  if (e instanceof Error /*CustomError*/) {
   console.log(e.message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is terribly ugly code, but...

```
// before
try {
  /*...*/ 
} catch (err) {
  if (err.name == 'AbortError') {
    /*...*/
  }
}

// after
try {
  /*...*/
} catch (err) {
  if ((err as {name?: string})?.name == 'AbortError') {
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Mostly I just want to be here for when people start adding better answers. Maybe TypeScript will have a better solution eventually.